# Bootstrap push my content to down when screen width reduce to half

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="container">
    <img style="float:left" src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="university logo">
    <h1  style="float:left;color:white;padding-top:20px;text-align:center;margin-left:10%"> Welcome To SURE Model</h1>
    <a style="float:left;margin-left:27%;margin-top:40px" (click)="logout()" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Log out </a>
</div>
```

this is full screen image
[image]

if i reduced to screen size to half it goes something like this
[image]

So how can i make this responsive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did float for 3 tags **img** **h1** **a** for that it pushing down to make responsive with bootstrap I suggest using class **.row** and inside it a class with **col-md** or **col-lg**  for secify paltform target